# Why does this function also work for 'R' when only name[0].lower() == "r" is mentioned?

Tags: python

I wrote a function that returned "(name) is playing banjo" when the name started with the letter "R" or "r". For instance "Rick is playing banjo", "ralph is playing banjo", "Nicci is not playing banjo" etc.

When I looked at the solution, I was surprised that "R" was not explicitly mentioned, but only name[0].lower() == 'r'.

```
def areYouPlayingBanjo(name):
return name + (' plays' if name[0].lower() == 'r' else ' does not play') + " banjo";
```

Maybe someone could explain this to me and everyone. Thanks!

Comment: lower returns a string with all lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because in your condition `if name[0].lower()` you are selecing the first value of the string variable `name` (which would be the first letter of the name) and then, afterwards you are applying `lower()` which will force the letter to be turned into lowercase. Therefore, regardless of the value being evaluated, it will always be lowercase. When compared with the criteria `== 'r'` using `lower()` first means you can forget about whether the name was written in uppercase or lowercase. This happens because python **IS** case sensitive, and it's easier than applying two conditions (`if name[0] =='r' OR if name[0] =='R'`).

```
def areYouPlayingBanjo(name):
return name + (' plays' if name[0].lower() == 'r' else ' does not play') + " banjo"
```

Vs.

```
def areYouPlayingBanjo(name):
return name + (' plays' if (name[0]=='r') | (name[0]=='R' else ' does not play') + " banjo"
```